# Recuperar dados da View asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, asp.net, entity-framework

Tenho seguinte problema, quando eu faço um pedido no campo quantidade quando eu colocar um determinado numero tenho que chegar se tem em estoque no banco, e se tiver diminiuir no banco a quantidade.porem não sei como passar o valor da view pra minha controler verificar isso.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <h4>Pedido</h4>
  <hr /> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Pedido_ProdutoId">Cliente</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("ClienteId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pedido.ClienteId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Pedido_ProdutoId">Produto</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("ProdutoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pedido.ProdutoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pedido.Quantidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pedido.Quantidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pedido.Quantidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  @*
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pedido.PrecoUnidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pedido.PrecoUnidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pedido.PrecoUnidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>*@

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

```
        // GET: Pedidos/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        Db db = new Db();

        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Cliente, "Id", "Nome");
        ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(db.Produto, "Id", "Nome");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Pedidos/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PedidoVM model)
    {
        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Cliente, "Id", "Nome");
        ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(db.Produto, "Id", "Nome");

        db.Pedido.Add(model.Pedido);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return View(model);

    }
```

Estoque

```
    [Table("Estoque")]
public class Estoque
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DepositoId { get; set; }

    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepositoId")]
    public virtual Deposito Deposito { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProdutoId")]
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

Pedido:

```
    [Table("Pedido")]
public class Pedido
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    public string Quantidade { get; set; }

    public decimal PrecoUnidade { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProdutoId")]
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi, você quer descontar a no estoque ao criar o pedido ou quer verificar a disponibilidade como validação da criação do pedido e informar ao usuário o limite disponível caso a quantidade desejada for maior que o estoque?

Comment: @ Leandro Angelo preciso fazer os 2, por exemplo se eu digitar 5 quanto eu tentar criar, ele  já verificar se tem em estoque e desconta, caso não tenha em estoque informo a msg, só to perdido nisso aí.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer a consulta no estoque e adicionar um erro na ModelState caso a quantidade solicitada for maior que a disponível.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PedidoVM model)
    {
        //Consulta a quantidade do produto no estoque
        var quantidadeEstoque = 5; 

        if(model.Pedido.Quantidade > quantidadeEstoque)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Pedido.Quantidade", string.Format("Existem apenas {0} items disponíveis no estoque.",  quantidadeEstoque));
        }


        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Persiste o pedido no banco
            //Desconta a quantidade no estoque

           return RedirectToAction("Sucesso);
        }

         return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado, só uma duvida , pra verificar o estoque estou tentando fazer isso:    var qtdEstoque = db.Estoque.Select(p => p.Quantidade).Where(p => p.produtoId ==  model.Pedido.ProdutoId)); mas no where ali não consigo acessar o produtoID

Comment: Posta o resto da sua view deveria vir pelo dropdown que você popula

Comment: @ Leandro Angelo Adiconei lá, o campo preço unidade ignore pq ele vai receber o valor referente ao id  do produto selecionado

Comment: @CesarAugusto, pela sua View, o produtoID não está dentro de pedido , talvez direto na PedidoVM, que você esqueceu de incluir na pergunta, mas como você monta pela ViewBag, talvez não esteja nem mapeado.

Comment: é eu removi a pedidoVM,  os valores do produto e cliente estão chegando, só estou com problema pra pegar a quantidade e valor unitario do produto selecionado
            var qtdEstoque = db.Estoque.Where(p => p.ProdutoId == model.ProdutoId).Select(p => p.Quantidade);
            var precoUnitario = db.Produto.Where(p => p.Id == model.ProdutoId).Select(p => p.Preco);

            model.PrecoUnidade = Convert.ToDecimal( precoUnitario);
            model.Quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(qtdEstoque);